# Workaround for permission troubles caused by move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php

I'm currently uploading images to my webserver using below PHP script. However, this causes permission troubles which I can not seem to change due to restrictions of webserver access. What's the best way to work around these permission warnings?

```
<?php
function upload_image()
{
    $target_dir = "../images/uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = true;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if ($check !== false) {
            $uploadOk = true;
        } else {
            $uploadOk = false;
            return "Sorry, file is not an image.";
        }
    }
// Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $uploadOk = false;
        return "Sorry, file already exists.";
    }
// Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 200000000) {
        $uploadOk = false;
        return "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    }
// Allow certain file formats
    if ($imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType != "JPEG"
        && $imageFileType != "GIF"
    ) {
        $uploadOk = false;
        return "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    }
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == false) {
        return "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            return basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        } else {
            return "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If php cannot write to the directory you want to write to, there is not much you can do in php to solve that. Unless there is another directory you are able to write to. Changing the permissions or ownership through your hosting control panel or something similar would be the most logical solution.

Comment: @jeroen So if I cannot access any control panel, there's nothing to do about this?

Comment: You need a directory other than the temporary directory to write to if you want to save your files. Theoretically you could store the images in a database as BLOBs but that is a horrible solution in my opinion. Or use an external file-hosting solution.

Comment: @jeroen I guess I have to live without it.

Comment: I don't know, a hosting service / solution where you cannot store files seems pretty useless to me.

Comment: @jeroen It's for demo purposes for a school assignment, It will be fine :-)